# ActionScript Parser written in ActionScript?

Tags: parsing, actionscript

I Know that there are several similar questions about ActionScript parsers, where I think the most appropriated answer is FlexPMD (http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexpmd/home/Home/). Sadly, this answer does not completely work for me, because I need the parser written in ActionScript, which allows me to manipulate the source code (eg. wrap all functions of source code).

In order to achieve my goal, I also read about meta-programing for AS3, but it seems to be  limited for my purpose.

Comment: What's your question? Are you looking for an AS parser?

Comment: @MattBall: His question is quite clear. I dunno why he got dinged; I'm sure it has improved his perception of SO as a useful source of information.  That said, I'd be pretty surprised if he found exactly what he wanted.

Comment: @IraBaxter. I found evales4 (http://eval.hurlant.com/), which could be useful for my purpose. EvalES4, which is written in AS3, is an interactive flash IDE for AS3 on the Web. In order to work, EvalES4 uses a parser. I would expect that Adobe proves an "official" parser of AS3, but I think I was wrong.

Comment: I'm sure Adobe has "the" reference parser for AS3. That's different that you can get them to give it to you, or that somebody else has it. Nor do they have a business motive that I can see, to bless somebody else's parser; it just creates trouble for them when people discover it doesn't quite match what Adobe's does.  The best you can hope for is some 3rd party (e.g., hurlant.com) to have built such a parser. Now you have to ask, why would they want you to have it?  Last hope: ANTLR/Bison style open-source grammar; FlexPMD you rejected.  As usual the real question is, what do you want to do?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I try instrumenting source code in order to get notifications of every event (eg. call a function) of the program execution.

Comment: Then any ActionScript parser should do, making your request for a parser specifically in Actionscript an unnecessary complicating factor.  ANTLR doesn't have one?

Comment: Finally, I used the metaas parser (http://www.badgers-in-foil.co.uk/projects/metaas/), which uses ANTLR. Although this parser is not exactly I was looking for, it is very is cool (you can parse and *(re)write* AS3 code).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but I came across this, which looks like possibly what you're looking for:

https://code.google.com/p/as3-commons/source/browse/trunk/as3-commons-asblocks/

Answer (score 1):

I've done [vegascriptparser](https://github.com/hydroper/vegascriptparser), which parses a near dialect ([VegaScript](https://github.com/vegascript/vegascript-reference)). The other parts, vegascriptparser-bytecode and vegascriptparser-semantic, will probably be done after reference.

Also the playful example on readme:

```
import vegascriptparser.*
import vegascriptparser.ast.*

const source = <![CDATA[
    trace(<{test ? 'x' : 'v'}/>)
    x?.v()
]]>.toString()

const program = Parser.quick(source).parse()
```

Turns into:

```
Program {
    directives: [
    ↪  ExpressionStatement { CallExpression {
            base: Identifier,
            args: [ ConditionalExpression, ],
        }}
    ↪  ExpressionStatement { OptionalExpression {
            base: Identifier,
            sub: CallExpression, 
        }]}
```